# JSON deserialization fails on Azure Api Service

Tags: json, azure, json-deserialization, azure-api-apps

### The Problem

I have a really big JSON file that i need to deserialize into a .NET object. To achieve this I use Newtonsoft.Json `JsonTextReader`. On a local machine the deserialization process runs without errors and the .NET object is fully filled with the values from the file. When I publish the code to an Azure Api Service the deserialization won't work.

When trying to parse the same file that worked locally i get this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Template' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path 'p2[0].p35[1].p125.p35[2].p125.p36[0].p200', line 1, position 35681.

I checked the object structure and compared it to the JSON file. The shown Path leads to an array in the JSON which should be converted to a collection of objects `ICollection<Blocks> Blocks` in the .NET object.

#### Additional information

Interestingly enough it **sometimes** also works within the Azure Api Service directly after the code is published. When the exception occurs restarting the Api Service won't help but publishing the same code again  fixes the error and the file gets deserialized correctly. Sooner or later the error shows up again and I have to publish the code again to get rid of it.

Before using the `JsonTextReader` to deserialize the JSON I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Package>(fileAsString)` which worked fine but getting the whole file as a string lead to OutOfMemory Exceptions with bigger files.

### The Code

This is the code for deserializing the object. The `JsonPropertyShortener` ContractResolver is used to replace the properties in the JSON file with shorter names to reduce file size and map them back to the right property names when deserializing.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(pkgStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
        serializer.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate;
        serializer.ContractResolver = JsonPropertyShortener.GetDeserializer(mapping);
        serializer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        return serializer.Deserialize<Package>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

### The Question(s)

Why is the deserialization not working correctly within an Azure Api Service when it works normally on a local machine?

What can I do to get it to work on the Azure Api Service?

*Bonus: Why does publishing the code mitigate the problem for some time?*

Comment: I have the same issue: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2054